# Верстка рейтинга

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно верстать систему рейтинга. Просто я не понимаю как правильно и задавать эти звезды, тип кнопкой или ссылкой? И что должно происходить при нажатии? Если можно по подробнее просто не шарю... [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `тип кнопкой или ссылкой?` -- делайте ссылкой, у кнопки нужно будет много лишних стилей убирать. `И что должно происходить при нажатии?` -- ну не знаю, а что вы хотите чтобы происходило?

Comment: Ссылка куда-то ведет, кнопка делает действия. Решайте.

Comment: @OliverPatterson не обязательно, всегда есть `href="#"` / `href="#!"` / `href="javascript:;"`.

Comment: @ΝNL993, но я не считаю, что так делать правильно.

Comment: @OliverPatterson как знаете, настаивать не буду :p

Comment: Вариантов как реализовать рейтинг - уйма, всё зависит от задачи и механики этого рейтинга (будет он только показывать или нажиматься тоже -> будут только целые значения или дробные, или всё разом -> можно ли поменять рейтинг, отображая предыдущую оценку или что-то другое, в общем много от простого до сложного). Если это учебное задание - то хоть картинкой цельной добавляйте. Хотите разобраться ищите примеры - их множество.

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/YzJzBWQ - вот смотрите

Answer (score 0):

Добавить каждой звезде id (1,2,3,4,5), но так же можно присваивать ID по типу: star1, star2 и т.д. Просто потом получать цифру. Потом используя javaScript обработать нажатия на них, для изменения кол-ва активных звезд.

```
// Получаем звезды
const stars = document.querySelectorAll("star")

// Обрабатываем нажатие:
stars.addEventListner("click", (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   let starID = e.target.id
   // Перебор звезд
   for(let i = 0; i < stars.length; i++){
      if(stars[i].id > starID){
         // Изменение класса на неактивный
         stars[i].setAttribute('class', 'star_disabled')
      }
   }
}, false)

// После этого можно добавить callback отправки данных на сервер или что либо в том же духе
```

Лучше сделать звезды кнопкой, но это не сильно принципиально

Надеюсь, что правильно понял ваш вопрос!

Comment: Объясните свою позицию, почему их лучше делать ссылкой?

Comment: @Oliver Patterson, перепутал, хотел написать кнопка, уже исправил

Comment: А зачем на них ид вешать? В чём сложно идентифицировать 5 звёзд в одном родительском элементе? Да и как это будет выглядеть, если это будет каталог товаров, где у каждой карточки будет рейтинг, будем добавлять "префикс" в айдишник?)

Comment: Я тут не пишу целое веб приложение, я лишь отвечаю на вопрос, тем более это лишь пример кода